# Closed unit disk is not homeomorphic to the real plane R^2?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am trying to proof that there is no homeomorphism between the closed unit disk and the real plane but i can't.Please help me.

Comment: What sort of topological invariants do you know?

Comment: Hint: Closed unit disk is closed and bounded. And what does this mean in real spaces?

Comment: I have seen these posts but i have no idea of homotopy theory. I have read the Munkre 's General topology.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a subset $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Now, compactness is a topological invariant, hence if the closed disk were homeomorphic to the plane, you would say that the plane is compact, absurd.

Comment: Is there any ideas why any open subset of the closed unit disk could not be homeomorphic to real plane?

Comment: @user391120 Any connected open subset of the closed unit disk *is* homeomorphic to the real plane. Take for instance the interior of the closed unit disk.

Comment: @ S. van Nigtevecht:Even if it consists of a part of the boundary of the closed unit circle?

Comment: @user391120: It's not true that *any* open subset of the closed unit disc is homeomorphic to the plane. The open disc minus the origin is a counterexample. If you wish to explore this issue further, you ought to post a separate question.